# Autoclose xml tags in C/C++ file in vim

Tags: c++, c, xml, vim

I have some documentation strings embedded within the source code (C/C++ files) as XML tags and I'd like to know what's the most minimal solution to make `vim` autoclose the tags (closest matching tag).

I've found `closetag.vim` but is there away to do this neatly without modifying anything but the `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim has no built-in support for that, so the *closetag.vim* plugin is the proper and easiest solution. (I use it myself, too!) Of course, you can develop your own simple mappings (that search backwards for an open tag, get that, drop the attributes, add the slash, and insert that), but:

- that will either be very simplistic and therefore often wrong
- or ends up with as much complexity as closetag, becoming a reimplementation of that plugin

If some rather strange restrictions (e.g. a custom primitive sync across systems) only allow you to manipulate the `~/.vimrc` itself, you could just append the entire plugin's code to it (though I'd recommend against such an ugly hack).