# Folding (expanding and colapsing) xml tags in vim (xml parsing)

Tags: vim, xml-parsing, macvim

I know that <kbd>%</kbd> in vim will jump from one tag to another, I also know how to use visual mode to select entire blocks between tags in an xml file, using <kbd>o</kbd> to jump from the top to the bottom tags.

I've done multiple web searches and have the matchit plugin installed using the following lines in my .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20925113/2871638), and have tried closetag.vim.

I review huge xml files and even with multiple monitors (and glasses) would find it useful to be able to collapse certain sections of the file.

---

### Is there a way to collapse and expand sections between tags in MacVim or vim by default or through the use of plugins?

Comment: I'm curious, how exactly are using `o` to jump between matching tags? That would be super useful, but `o` in visual mode doesn't do anything for me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The feature you need is called "folding".

Basically, you tell Vim to use one of its available `'foldmethod'` and manage each line's `'foldlevel'` with commands like `za`, `zr` or `zM`. You can find all the details in `:help folding`.

Adding these lines to your `vimrc` should provide a good starting point:

```
augroup XML
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType xml setlocal foldmethod=indent foldlevelstart=999 foldminlines=0
augroup END
```

With these settings, all folds should be open when you load a file, the fold level of each line should be derived from its indentation and you should be able to fold away single lines.

Use `zm` to fold more, `zr` to fold less, `zc` to close a fold, `zo` to open it, `za` to toggle between those two states, `zM` to close every fold, `zR` to open them and so on…

Documentation:

```
:help folding
:help 'foldmethod'
:help 'foldlevelstart'
:help 'foldminlines'
```

Comment: @romainl, what about non-intended XML file? Just intend it using ggG= and do the same? Or is there any other options to fold which can achieve this without relying on intendation?

Comment: On non-indented XML you could try the `syntax` foldmethod or (better IMO) reformat it and use `indent`.

Comment: In my experience, the `syntax` foldmethod does a better job of collapsing in a way that shows the parent tags instead of the first child.

Answer (score 28):

The indent method almost worked for me, but I found the way it worked to be a little bit strange; essentially, it folded on the *content* of the tags instead of the tags themselves. This worked for me, from [the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_XML_Editor):

```
let g:xml_syntax_folding=1
au FileType xml setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

This method folds on the actual tags themselves, for example:

```
<MyLines group="first">
    <Foo value="1"/>
    <Foo value="2"/>
    <Foo value="3"/>
</MyLines>
<MyLines group="second">
    <Foo value="4"/>
    <Foo value="5"/>
    <Foo value="6"/>
</MyLines>
```

Looks like this after typing `zc` on line 1 or 5:

```
+--  5 lines: <MyLines group="first">------------------------------------
<MyLines group="second">
    <Foo value="4"/>
    <Foo value="5"/>
    <Foo value="6"/>
</MyLines>
```

Instead of:

```
+-- 10 lines: <MyLines group="first">------------------------------------
```

Comment: This solved my problem, just remember to add `syntax on`

Comment: This is my favorite answer since it has a bare minimum number of commands.

Comment: Might need to edit (`:e`) the file again for the `au` command to take effect.

Answer (score 11):

This is taken from as @adam_0's answer, but using autocommand (as per @romani's answer), and with `syntax on` included as per @Paul's comment.

```
augroup XML
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType xml let g:xml_syntax_folding=1
    autocmd FileType xml setlocal foldmethod=syntax
    autocmd FileType xml :syntax on
    autocmd FileType xml :%foldopen!
augroup END
```

The `:%foldopen!` line at the end opens all folds so that the file is WYSWIG when you load the file.  But `zM` and friends are immediately available for folding if you want.

Comment: you can activate this for several files with `autocmd FileType xml,ui,xhtml,html`

Comment: I prefer substitute `autocmd FileType xml :%foldopen!` with `autocmd FileType xml normal zR`